# Access child class instance in parent

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

In Python I have a dictionary of settings which relate to a task class. In the parent constructor of these tasks I would like to store only the relevant settings, but to do this I need to access the child class from the parent class.

```
settings = {
    SomeTask: { 'foo': 'bar' },
    SomeOtherTask: { 'bar': 'foo' },
}

class SomeTask(BaseTask):
    pass

class SomeOtherTask(BaseTask):
    pass

class BaseTask:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings[child_class]
```

In PHP I can do this by calling `get_class($this);` in the constructor (returns the child class name rather than the parent), does Python have something similar?

Comment: You do realize the definitions are precisely in the wrong order?

Comment: Yep, I did this deliberately as it makes more sense (to me) to describe it this way - although that might just be me?

Comment: self(or really the first argument in class methods) always refers to the instanstiated class you are working with

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh that's right, it seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
class BaseTask:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings[self.__class__]

class SomeTask(BaseTask):
    pass

class SomeOtherTask(BaseTask):
    pass
```

When you initialise one of the child classes with the settings, they will do what you expect.

Comment: Can this be done without creating a circular reference though?

Comment: @Aya There's no circular reference (and even if there was, it wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Alternatively, `type(self)`, which is closer to the PHP version and more idiomatic. Plus, it breaks on old-style classes so you're forced to use new-style classes ;-)

Comment: @delnan Oops. Didn't notice the `settings` param. I thought the code was using the global.

Answer (score 1):

The closest Python equivalent to the PHP code...

```
$class_name = get_class($my_object)
```

...is...

```
class_name = my_object.__class__.__name__
```

...which should work for both old-style and new-style Python classes.

Indeed, if you index the classes by their name, rather than using a reference to the class object, then you don't need to pass in the `settings` parameter (which I assume you only did to avoid a circular reference), and access the global `settings` variable directly...

```
settings = {
    'SomeTask': { 'foo': 'bar' },
    'SomeOtherTask': { 'bar': 'foo' },
}

class BaseTask:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = settings[self.__class__.__name__]

class SomeTask(BaseTask):
    pass

class SomeOtherTask(BaseTask):
    pass
```

Comment: Going by class name is pretty fragile in general. Even going my module name + qualified name in module is quite hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I would it consider much cleaner to do

```
class SomeTask(BaseTask):
    settings = { 'foo': 'bar' }

class SomeOtherTask(BaseTask):
    settings = { 'bar': 'foo' }
```

provided no changes are made to these settings.

This way, the changes are tightly coupled to the class and there is only one dict object containing these settings.

Comment: In practice it's a bit more complicated - more like `settings = { 'client1': { SomeTask: {} }, 'client2': { OtherTask: {} } }`. But I agree if that were the case :)